# Customize fastScrollOverlay?

Tags: android, styles, scroll

I'm trying to customize the letter popup that appears during scroll. I was able to change it's colors and the position from my styles, but I need to make the text and the whole element bigger as well as move it closer to the vertical center of the screen. Is any of these things possible? How can I do them?

This is my current code from my style.xml file:

```
    <item name="android:fastScrollOverlayPosition">floating</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollTextColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundLeft">@drawable/square</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@drawable/square</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any info about further customization of the default overlay.

There's a more flexible alternative, though.  You could add a `TextView` to your layout which only appears when the user is scrolling, and show the letter returned from your `SectionIndexer`'s `getPositionForSection` method.  You could then style this view exactly to your liking, and center it in a full-screen `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a great idea. Do you know how to hide the default overlay?

Comment: You know, it doesn't look like there's a way!  I actually implemented my own fast scroll, which involved using a thin vertical strip on the side of my listview, on which I placed the letters of the alphabet from top to bottom.  On touch, I calculated the percent to scroll through the list, and showed my custom overlay during that time.  Not sure if that's an option for you.

Comment: I just had another thought on this.  If your design permits it, you could create a custom overlay which actually obscures the default.  It's an ugly workaround, but would serve your purposes.